# Understanding Hibernate transactions

Tags: hibernate, transactions

I understand that a transaction helps to rollback update operations if anything goes wrong such as a code exception or if the database is down. What I do not understand is the following:

In [this page](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch13.html#transactions-demarcation):

> 13.2. Database transaction demarcation
>
> Database, or system, transaction boundaries are always necessary. No
> communication with the database can occur outside of a database
> transaction (this seems to confuse many developers who are used to the
> auto-commit mode). Always use clear transaction boundaries, even for
> read-only operations

This one says that a transaction should be used in all cases, even for **read-only operations** !

- Why is it a must ? Shouldn't I do so only when I'm about to update the database ?
- If it's a must, why isn't it started automatically when a session is obtained ?

Regarding the following quoted paragraph (On [this page](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch02.html#architecture-overview)).

> Transaction (org.hibernate.Transaction)
>
> (Optional) A single-threaded, short-lived object used by the application to specify
> atomic units of work. It abstracts the application from the underlying JDBC, JTA or
> CORBA transaction. A org.hibernate.Session might span several
> org.hibernate.Transactions in some cases. However, transaction
> demarcation, either using the underlying API or
> org.hibernate.Transaction, is never optional.

What is meant by the first word `(Optional)` indicate ?

And what does this statement mean too ?

`However, transaction demarcation, either using the underlying API or org.hibernate.Transaction, is never optional.` ?!

Also I understand from [this page](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch01.html), that whenever I open a Hibernate session whether to update or load an object, I **must** start a transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to start a transaction for a load operation. You only need it if your operation may do an update and you want commit/rollback semantics in case something else fails within that scope. So the hibernate transaction is just a scope and will use the underlying transaction of the database when needed, such as when getting a connection the first time. If it is in a transaction, then that connection will be used for the life of the transaction scope instead of being returned to the pool for each sql operation, which is what happens without hibernate transactions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But actually docs emphasize on using a transaction even for read-only operations. I clarified my question more.

Comment: Its misleading doc to some degree. Its only necessary to declare explicit transactions when multiple operations must be atomic and have all or nothing change semantics. However, in some cases you can induce read-locks and you may want them to persist for multiple reads. I agree with you, the doc is a little misleading.

Comment: Based on this article, you don't need transactions for read-only operations only if you enable auto_commit https://community.jboss.org/wiki/Non-transactionalDataAccessAndTheAuto-commitMode